# How to make hibernate unidirectional many-to-many association updateable?

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-many, updates

I have two entities - `Category` and `Attribute`. `Category` can have multiple related attributes, and `Attribute` can be related to any number of categories. Association should be available only on `Category` side - `Attribute` objects are not aware of categories they are related to.

So I model this association as unidirectional many-to-many:

Category.hbm.xml

```
<class name="Category" table="category" proxy="ICategory" entity-name="category">
  <id name="id" column="id" unsaved-value="null"><generator class="identity" /></id>
  ...some properties...
  <bag name="relatedAttributes" table="category_attribute" fetch="select">
    <key column="id_category" />
    <many-to-many column="id_attribute" entity-name="attribute" />
  </bag>
</class>
```

and Attribute.hbm.xml

```
<class name="Attribute" table="attribute" proxy="IAttribute" entity-name="attribute">
  <id name="id" column="id" unsaved-value="null" ><generator class="identity" /></id>
  ...some properties...
</class>
```

Mapping works perfectly with current data until it needs an update. I just want to do things as simple as these:

```
ICategory c = (ICategory) session.get("category", 1);
c.getRelatedAttributes().add((IAttribute) session.get("attribute", 2));
session.update("category", c);
```

**How can i make this association updateable?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally done. Changes that affect behavior:

```
<bag name="relatedAttributes" table="category_attribute" fetch="select" inverse="false" cascade="save-update">
  ...
</bag>
```

and do not forget to call `session.flush()` after operations.